# Thread switching

Tags: multithreading, c#-2.0

How to execute the callback method in same thread which calls Asynchronous function.
the caller thread may not be UI Thread... But UI Should not hang..

Thanks & Regards,
Dinesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic bullet that will allow one thread to initiate the execution of a delegate onto another thread. The target thread must be specially constructed to allow this. In the case of the UI thread there is a message pump that dispatches and processes messages. This message pump can be used to perform the marshaling operation via the `ISynchronizeInvoke` interface.

```
ISynchronizeInvoke target = someForm; // where someForm is a Form or Control
target.Invoke(
  (Action)(() =>
  {
    MessageBox.Show("I am on the target thread");
  }), null);
```

In your case the thread calling the asynchronous function must have some kind of producer-consumer mechanism built into it to get a callback to execute asynchronously on that thread after it has been instructed to do so from the worker thread. Unfortunately, this is not a trivial problem to solve.

Here is one way you can create a thread that can accept delegates to be executed.

```
public class SynchronizeInvokeThread : ISynchronizeInvoke
{
    private Thread m_Thread;
    private BlockingCollection<WorkItem> m_Collection = new BlockingCollection<WorkItem>();

    public SynchronizeInvokeThread()
    {
        m_Thread = new Thread(
            () =>
            {
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new MySynchronizationContext(this));
                while (true)
                {
                    WorkItem wi = m_Collection.Take();
                    wi.Complete(wi.Method.DynamicInvoke(wi.Args));
                }
            });
        m_Thread.Start();
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
    {
        var wi = new WorkItem(method, args);
        m_Collection.Add(wi);
        return wi;
    }

    public object EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var wi = (WorkItem)result;
        wi.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        return wi.Result;
    }

    public object Invoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
    {
        var wi = new WorkItem(method, args);
        m_Collection.Add(wi);
        wi.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
        return wi.Result;
    }

    public bool InvokeRequired
    {
        get { return Thread.CurrentThread != m_Thread; }
    }

    private class MySynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
    {
        private ISynchronizeInvoke m_SynchronizingObject;

        public MySynchronizationContext(ISynchronizeInvoke synchronizingObject)
        {
            m_SynchronizingObject = synchronizingObject;
        }

        public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
        {
            m_SynchronizingObject.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { state });
        }

        public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
        {
            m_SynchronizingObject.Invoke(d, new object[] { state });
        }
    }

    private class WorkItem : IAsyncResult
    {
        private Delegate m_Method;
        private object[] m_Args;
        private object m_Result = null;
        private ManualResetEvent m_Signal = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public WorkItem(Delegate method, object[] args)
        {
            m_Method = method;
            m_Args = args;
        }

        public void Complete(object result)
        {
            m_Result = result;
            m_Signal.Set();
        }

        public object Result
        {
            get { return m_Result; }
        }

        public Delegate Method
        {
            get { return m_Method; }
        }

        public object[] Args
        {
            get { return m_Args; }
        }

        public object AsyncState
        {
            get { return null; }
        }

        public WaitHandle AsyncWaitHandle
        {
            get { return m_Signal; }
        }

        public bool CompletedSynchronously
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get { return m_Signal.WaitOne(0); }
        }
    }
}
```

It can be used like this.

```
ISynchronizeInvoke target = new SynchronizeInvokeThread(); 
target.Invoke(
  (Action)(() =>
  {
    Console.WriteLine("I am on the target thread");
    SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(
      (state) =>
      {
        Console.WriteLine("I even have a synchronization context!");
      }, null);
  }), null);
```

**Update:**

Per the comment below `BlockingCollection` is only available in .NET 4.0 or as part of the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) download. If this data structure is not available to you then this already difficult code just became even harder.

Comment: @Brain Gideon: using `CustomThread` will not invoke a code in the target thread. it is because you don't use `SynchronizationContext`... to prove it. run a test at windows forms and replace the `Console.WriteLine` with `textBox1.Text = "some data";` you will have a cross thread exception.. Also note that you are using `ConcurrentCollection` where the question tag is `C# 3.0`

Comment: The target thread is `CustomThread` and it certainly does marshal a delegate onto *that* thread. One of my points was to demonstrate just how much is involved in getting that to work with a non-UI thread since the OP did state that a non-UI thread could be a target. The exception occurs because you are attempting to access a `Control` from a thread other than the hosting thread, but that only proves that the target thread was a non-UI thread. If you wanted the target thread to be a UI thread you would obviously use `Control.Invoke` instead. Fair point on C# 3.0 though :)

Comment: @Brain: No that will not work even in Console application test at Console main: 
        `Console.WriteLine("Thread Id: \"{0}\"", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        CustomThread thread = new CustomThread();
        thread.Invoke(
          (Action)(() =>
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Thread Id: \"{0}\"", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
          }), null);`
 the output will be something like: `Thread Id: 9       Thread Id: 10`

Comment: @Jalal: It does work. I tested it before I posted it. What you observe is exactly what *should* happen. You were able to to inject a method call onto thread 10 (target) from thread 9 (main). This clearly proves that we have created a non-UI target thread that can accept delegate injections using `ISynchronizeInvoke` just like a normal UI thread.

Comment: @Jalal: I think there may some confusion about `SynchronizationContext`. Not all threads have one. In fact, most do not. You have to actually subclass `SynchronizationContext` and then attach it to the target thread before it can be extracted from `SynchronizationContext.Current`. I updated my answer to provide the context on the target thread which was **easy** since I already had the plumbing in place to get the target thread to accept delegate injections.

Comment: @Brain: Now this will work; after you added `SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(` :), but it will only work if the `SynchronizatioinContext.Current` is not null. by default the framework are implementing `Current` only in `windows forms` and `wpf` so when using this default `Current` here you will actually invoke the method in the UI thread. However it is true that the solution is to `actually subclass SynchronizationContext and then attach it to the target thread before it can be extracted from SynchronizationContext.Current`.

Comment: @Jalal: That is not correct. Calling `SynchronizationContext.Current.Post` in my example will not execute the delegate in the UI thread. It will, in fact, asynchronously execute it in the calling thread which is the non-UI target thread I explicitly created. It would work exactly the same had I replaced the call with `target.BeginInvoke` instead. That is the point. A `SynchroninzationContext` is only needed if you are using APIs that require it like the TPL. The point of my code is to demonstrate how to get **any arbitrary thread** to accept delegate injections.

Comment: @Brian: because of the `SynchronizationContext.Current` is _only_ by default initialized when using `win forms` and `wpf` then it will marshal code execution in the main thread which is the UI thread. calling `Send` or the asynchronous `Post` method will execute code on the UI thread. for example you can update a UI control by using it without having `cross thread exeption`, test it: `SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(new SendOrPostCallback((_) => { textBox1.Text = "New!"; }), null);`

Comment: @Jalal: That is true *only* if the calling thread is a UI thread. It will fail on all others. I just tested it. Let me pose a question. How would *you* inject a delegate into an arbitrary thread (one that might not be a UI thread)? That is what the OP asked. Can you update your answer to provide a solution to that problem?

Comment: @Brian: My solution is just similar to yours `after you added SynchronizationContext.Current` however it is true that it will fail on all others but because of the `SynchornizationContext.Current` is null. And the poster was asking `to execute the callback method in same thread` not `How would you inject a delegate into an arbitrary thread`.

Comment: @Jalal: No, it is nothing like mine. Read the OP's question again. Some thread (call it `A`) calls an asynchronous method. Asynchronous methods typically do their work on a separate thread (call it `B`). Per the OP, the callback from the asynchronous method must be executed on `A` which could be a non-UI thread. To get that callback originating from `B` executing on `A` it has to be injected into `A`. `A` has to be specially structured to accept delegate injections. My solution is the only one that matches the requirements...so far anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use a BackgroundWorker. The callback will be on the owning thread.

If the asynchronous operation needs to be on-running even after the callback, you can make multiple callbacks using the WPF System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke/BeginInvoke...or if WinForms, you can use the form or control instance itself and call Invoke/BeginInvoke.

Comment: If it is a console application then BackgroundWorker's Completed event is called in Different thread.. In which we are calling RunAsync fnction..

Answer (score 0):

Like `Brian Gideon` mentioned out you should use [ISynchronizeInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.aspx) "System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke".  Implement it on the class that you want to marshal its thread execution on another thread. Here example `Media` class "some class I implemented was interacting with Com object so it should execute its methods in the main thread"; because of the class implementation it uses `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current` so you can use it in WindowsForms but not a Console application because the System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current is null.

Whenever you want to marshal the execution of this class into the thread that created it just call its `Invoke` method.

```
public abstract class Media : ISynchronizeInvoke
{
        //....

        private readonly System.Threading.SynchronizationContext _currentContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;

        private readonly System.Threading.Thread _mainThread = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread;

        private readonly object _invokeLocker = new object();
        //....


        #region ISynchronizeInvoke Members

        public bool InvokeRequired
        {
            get
            {
                return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId != this._mainThread.ManagedThreadId;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is not supported!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="method"></param>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Obsolete("This method is not supported!", true)]
        public IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is not supported!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="method"></param>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Obsolete("This method is not supported!", true)]
        public object EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }

        public object Invoke(Delegate method, object[] args)
        {
            if (method == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("method");
            }

            lock (_invokeLocker)
            {
                object objectToGet = null;

                SendOrPostCallback invoker = new SendOrPostCallback(
                delegate(object data)
                {
                    objectToGet = method.DynamicInvoke(args);
                });

                _currentContext.Send(new SendOrPostCallback(invoker), method.Target);

                return objectToGet;
            }
        }

        public object Invoke(Delegate method)
        {
            return Invoke(method, null);
        }

        #endregion//ISynchronizeInvoke Members

}
```